# Trying to pair 2 items from a vector but use them only once

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, random

I'm not sure how descriptive my title is but hopefully some clicked and will better understand what I mean here.

I am making a simple game and the function that I want to create should take an item from an array (name) and one from the other (role) and pair them together to form "name-role" which will be added in the other vector.

My first version had me trying to use rand() with all numbers under 13 but I found myself having to wait around 30 minutes after the first 6 items because, obviously, it would take some time until it would get another index that wasn't already used. I tried to use some vectors with items, extract random number from them and then delete that number so it will be much faster but it's stuck in a loop and I'm not really sure why. I worked on this for a long time and started getting very confused and tired from my own code, so if someone could help me that'd be great.

My current non-working code:

```
std::vector<std::string> gGetResidents()
{
    std::string gPlayers[12]{ "Deodat Lawson", "James Bayley", "Edward Bishop", "Rebecca Nurse", "Sarah Good",
    "Bridget Bishop", "Sarah Wildes", "Elizabeth Howe", "John Proctor", "Martha Carrier", "George Burroughs",
    "Giles Corey" };

    std::string gRoles[12]{ "Jailor", "Sheriff", "Investigator", "Vigilante", "Doctor", "Bodyguard", "Lookout",
    "Escort", "Godfather", "Mafioso", "Consort", "Framer" };

    std::vector<size_t> gUsed;

    std::vector<std::string> gMetaResidents;

    for (size_t gInd{ 0 }; gInd < 12; ++gInd)
    {
    gLabel:

        std::vector<size_t> gNumbersPlayer{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };

        std::vector<size_t> gNumbersRole{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };

        srand(time(nullptr));
        size_t gRandomPositionPlayer = rand() % gNumbersPlayer.size();
        size_t gRandomPositionRole = rand() % gNumbersRole.size();

        std::cout << "siz : " << gNumbersPlayer.size() << "\n\n";

        std::cout << "rand pos pl : " << gRandomPositionPlayer << " rand pos rol : " << gRandomPositionRole << "\n\n";

        size_t gRandomPlayer{ 0 };
        size_t gRandomRole{ 0 };

        if(gRandomPositionPlayer < gNumbersPlayer.size() && std::find(gNumbersPlayer.begin(), gNumbersPlayer.end(), gRandomPositionPlayer) != gNumbersPlayer.end())
        {
            gRandomPlayer = gNumbersPlayer[gRandomPositionPlayer -1];
            gNumbersPlayer.erase(gNumbersPlayer.begin() + gRandomPositionPlayer);
        }

        std::cout << "rand pl : " << gRandomPlayer;

        if (gRandomPositionRole < gNumbersRole.size() && std::find(gNumbersRole.begin(), gNumbersRole.end(), gRandomPositionRole) != gNumbersRole.end())
        {
            gRandomRole = gNumbersRole[gRandomPositionRole - 1];
            gNumbersRole.erase(gNumbersRole.begin() + gRandomPositionRole);
        }

        std::cout << " rand rol : " << gRandomRole << "\n\n";

        if (std::find(gUsed.begin(), gUsed.end(), gRandomPlayer) != gUsed.end())
            goto gLabel;

        if (std::find(gUsed.begin(), gUsed.end(), gRandomRole) != gUsed.end())
            goto gLabel;

        gUsed.push_back(gRandomPlayer);
        gUsed.push_back(gRandomRole);

        std::string gCombinedUn = gPlayers[gRandomPlayer].append(" is the ");
        std::string gCombined = gCombinedUn.append(gRoles[gRandomRole]);

        gMetaResidents.push_back(gCombined);

        gCombinedUn.clear();
        gCombined.clear();

        std::cout << gRandomPlayer << " - " << gRandomRole << "\n";
    }

    return gMetaResidents;
}
```

P.S.: The couts are from me trying to debug the game (despite being able to do it from my IDE, I just prefer doing this for some odd reason, so, ignore them.

Comment: First of all, don't call `srand` *inside* the loop. It will reset the seed each iteration. Do it *once* at the start of the program.

Comment: As for your problem, if you want a unique *set* of numbers, you could get a little help with [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) to store your random values. Then you could easily loop getting random values until you get one which isn't in the set.

Comment: Lastly, using `goto` is often discouraged. Especially when there are other in-language constructs that can be used instead. Like a [`continue` statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue).

Comment: I'm going to try your first two things you mentioned, but as for goto, I know what people say about it but I cannot use continue in my example. I could but it would get messier, so I'd rather just keep it, it's not such a big deal I'd figure. Thanks man, I'll try what you said and come back

Comment: @ShaggyDoo -- One of the bad uses of `goto` is your example.  You are branching *up* to a label which is far worse than branching down to a label.  What you should replace that with is `do..while()`.

Comment: Okay, will replace it. If you could give me some idea of how I would work this out with set, that'd be great. I've never used it before and the documentation is kind of unintelligible for me

Comment: @ShaggyDoo A `std::set` is a container that does not store duplicates.  You keep calling `set::insert()` until the `set` reaches your desired limit.

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out. I'll see if I can get it to work and be back

Comment: Ok I think I became even more confused. How is this any different from my vector way?